# How do I inject CSS/JS in a WKWebView using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, webkit

I'm new to SwiftUI and trying to inject some custom CSS/JS into a page loaded with WKWebView:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
 
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com")!)
        
        WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: [WKWebsiteDataTypeDiskCache, WKWebsiteDataTypeMemoryCache], modifiedSince: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0), completionHandler:{ })

        webView.load(request)
        webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(WKUserScript( source: "alert('debug')", injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true))
    }
}
```

Which is load like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebView()
    }
}
```

Sadly, the code doesn't seem to actually inject anything. I've tried running it before `webView.load` as well. Having been googling quite a bit, I only see [examples](https://medium.com/@mahdi.mahjoobi/injection-css-and-javascript-in-wkwebview-eabf58e5c54e) done in UIKit and unfortunately, I'm too inexperienced to wrap UIKit in a way that I can use with SwiftUI.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, have you tried moving the code inside `makeUIView` instead of `updateUIView`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @alobaili. Unfortunately, it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all try to avoid including business code in your views whenever you can. You may use two functions in the Webkit API if you want to include/inject JS to the webview content: *EvaluateJS* and *AddUserScript*. You may use "AddUserScript" before the "load" starts. Also please not that "alert" function in JS, would not work in current Mobile Safari. You should have see the text colors to appear in blue with the script below.

**Result:**

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      CustomWebview()
    }
    .padding()
  }
}
struct SwiftUIWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
  typealias UIViewType = WKWebView
  
  let webView: WKWebView
  
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    webView
  }
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
  }
}

final class SwiftUIWebViewModel: ObservableObject {
  
  @Published var addressStr = "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
  
  let webView: WKWebView
  init() {
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    loadUrl()
  }
  
  func loadUrl() {
    guard let url = URL(string: addressStr) else {
      return
    }
    
    webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(WKUserScript( source: """
window.userscr ="hey this is prior injection";
""", injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false))
    
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    // You will have the chance in 8 seconds to open Safari debugger if needed. PS: Also put a breakpoint to injectJS function.
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 8.0) {
      self.injectJS()
    }
  }
  
  func injectJS () {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("""
      window.temp = "hey here!";
document.getElementById("content").style.color = "blue";
""")
  }
}
struct CustomWebview: View {
  
  @StateObject private var model = SwiftUIWebViewModel()
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      SwiftUIWebView(webView: model.webView)
      
        .padding()
    }
  }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```